# Error 1 Error 2 on Conference MVC Tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi there im following the series of [MVC tutorials given by microsoft](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start-8239?l=Dth6ApJy_8104984382) and i came across this problem:

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbSet.Add(Conference.Models.Session)'
>   has some invalid arguments    visual studio
>   2013\Projects\Conference\Conference\Models\ConferenceContextInitializer.cs    18  31  Conference
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Conference.Models.Speaker' to
>   'Conference.Models.Session'   visual studio
>   2013\Projects\Conference\Conference\Models\ConferenceContextInitializer.cs    19  34  Conference

ConferenceModelInitializer

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Conference.Models
{
    public class ConferenceContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ConferenceContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(ConferenceContext context)
        {
            context.Sessions.Add(
                new Session()
                {
                    Title = "I Want Spaghetti",
                    Abstract = "The Life and times of a spaghetti lover",
                    Speaker = context.Speakers.Add(
                                 new Speaker()
                                 {
                                     Name = "Jon Pepe",
                                     EmailAddress = "jon@asfdasd.com"
                                 })
                });
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

ConferenceContext

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Conference.Models
{
    public class ConferenceContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Session> Speakers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The second line should be `public DbSet<Speaker> Speakers { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
public class ConferenceContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Session> Speakers { get; set; }
}
```

with:

```
public class ConferenceContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Speaker> Speakers { get; set; } //since you are referencing the speaker class here
}
```